# Cumulative sum over groups on SQL 5.7

Tags: mysql-5.7

I work on MySQL 5.7 with a table that looks like this:

```
 num  id   count
 1    1    100
 2    1    50
 1    2    10
 2    2    100
 1    3    50
 2    3    10
```

I want to add a new column called cumulative_sum, so the table would look like this:

```
num id   count  cumulative_sum
1   1    100    100
2   1    50     150
1   2    10     10
2   2    100    120
1   3    50     50
2   3    10     60
```

Is there a MySQL update statement that can do this easily? What's the best way to accomplish this? The most examples I find are with defined variables or subqueries.

Comment: I have given you a MySQL 5.7 option below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 5.7, we can use a correlated subquery to find the rolling sum:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    count,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.count) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.num <= t1.num) cumulative_sum
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    id,
    num
```

On MySQL 8+, we can use `SUM` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    count,
    SUM(count) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY num) cumulative_sum
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    id,
    num;
```

Comment: In my case, the tables t1 and t2 are the same and syntatically long in characters. I saw a solution using defined variables (aka @). Do  you think it is possible in this case?

Comment: Maybe.  User variables are deprecated in MySQL 8+, so you should probably move away from using them.

Comment: I think there must be a clever way cumulative sum my query of (necessary) 367 lines.

Comment: I have given you clever ways.

Comment: I will copy paste my table on "yourTable"